# how can I print out 2 LL?

Tags: javascript

```js
var str = "ahceclwlxo";
for (var i = 1; i <str.length; i+=2){
    console.log(str[i]);
}
```

in my browser again problem, here it shows correct like "hello" but in my browser it shows "he2Lo", where the problem?i am confused really

Comment: If you are looking at the results in the console, perhaps what you see is the console telling you it combined the two duplicate messages

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing in your console is an output of occurrences for each of the `console.log`s so the `2l` is really just saying there are two occurrences of `l` being logged.

**Example Console Output**

[image]

Here's your code again, but this time with the code being added to an array, then the array being printed.

```
var str = "ahceclwlxo";
var result = []
for (var i = 1; i <str.length; i+=2){
  result.push(str[i])
}
console.log(result)
```

That prints out `(5) ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]` in chrome's console. Indicating that you have an array with a length of 5.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is *exactly* an explanation of the issue!

Comment: @JonSG Likely because it seems this is the second time they've asked nearly the same question. This should really have been closed as a duplicate of the first.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ahh, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers' console windows are configured to not actually reprint similar outputs repeatedly. Instead they print out the first copy and display the number of repetitions.